# xml replace value with formula by xsl and create csv from php

Tags: php, xml, csv, xslt

I have a XML feed from supplier ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<maps>
  <map>
    <sku>1534133010</sku>
    <name>10 LED dekor. řetěz - sníh 2M IP44 modrá</name>
    <price>165,0000</price>
    <qty>0</qty>
  </map>
</maps>
```

I need the price convert according as formula:

```
=IIf([map]![price]<="100";[map]![price]*1,43;IIf([map]![price]<="300";[map]![price]*1,4;IIf([map]![price]<="500";[map]![price]*1,38;IIf([map]![price]<="700";[map]![price]*1,35;IIf([map]![price]>"1200";[map]![price]*1,34;0)))))
```

and price rounded to integer.

And complete convert to CSV.

Desire output of CSV:

```
sku,name,price,qty
1534133010,10 LED dekor. řetěz - sníh 2M IP44 modrá,220,0
```

I tried following but not working..

PHP script:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('sample.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('transformace.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$newDOM = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
$newDOM->formatOutput = true;
$newDOM->save("newfile.xml")
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="windows-1250" />   
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <maps>
        <xsl:for-each select="SHOP/SHOPITEM">
        <map>
          <sku><xsl:value-of select="CODE"/></sku>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCT"/></name>
          <price><xsl:value-of select="format-number( round(100*'price) div 100 ,"##0.00" )"/></price>
          <qty><xsl:value-of select="AVAILABILITY"/></qty>      
        </map>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </maps>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Have anybody ideas how do it?

Comment: You have not named the supplier. This is important information and missing with your question. XML is a very generic file format. It most often transports more information and format application. You have not provided any specification of the file you're going to operate on. The information of the file-format-specification is therefore missing with your question. I would vote to close as unclear, but let me look if it can be quickly closed against a duplicate instead. -- **Additionally** please make yourself comfortable with the editing help to properly format your question, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the price according to your formula, you first need to convert the price to a number, by replacing the decimal comma with a decimal dot.

Then use `xsl:choose` to apply the appropriate multiplier for each price level.

Here's an example, using a **minimized** test input:

**XML**

```
<maps>
  <map>
    <sku>12345</sku>
    <price>100,0000</price>
  </map>
  <map>
    <sku>12346</sku>
    <price>300,0000</price>
  </map>
  <map>
    <sku>12347</sku>
    <price>500,0000</price>
  </map>
  <map>
    <sku>12348</sku>
    <price>700,0000</price>
  </map>
  <map>
    <sku>12349</sku>
    <price>800,0000</price>
  </map>
</maps>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/maps">
    <maps>
        <xsl:for-each select="map">
            <map>
                <sku><xsl:value-of select="sku"/></sku>
                <price>
                    <xsl:variable name="price" select="translate(price, ',', '.')" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$price &lt;= 100">
                            <xsl:value-of select="round($price * 1.43)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$price &lt;= 300">
                            <xsl:value-of select="round($price * 1.4)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$price &lt;= 500">
                            <xsl:value-of select="round($price * 1.38)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$price &lt;= 700">
                            <xsl:value-of select="round($price * 1.35)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="round($price * 1.34)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </price>
            </map>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </maps>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<maps>
   <map>
      <sku>12345</sku>
      <price>143</price>
   </map>
   <map>
      <sku>12346</sku>
      <price>420</price>
   </map>
   <map>
      <sku>12347</sku>
      <price>690</price>
   </map>
   <map>
      <sku>12348</sku>
      <price>945</price>
   </map>
   <map>
      <sku>12349</sku>
      <price>1072</price>
   </map>
</maps>
```

**Note**:

1. Your XSLT addresses elements that do not appear in your input, such as
   SHOP, SHOPITEM CODE and PRODUCT. Either your input is very different
   from what you show us, or your XSLT is irrelevant to the input;
2. Your formula has a gap between `<=700` and `>1200`;
3. I cannot help wondering why the price needs to be adjusted in this
   way; normally you see the price adjusted by **quantity**, not by
   itself.

I suggest you ask a separate question regarding CSV output, as it has nothing to do with the above problem.